# How to make this title in a title page?

Tags: titles, typography, book-design, page, frame-title

I would like to reproduce the following title in my title page given by the code below (this picture was done using *Pages*, from Apple):

[image]

Here's my title page code to work with:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype,lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{1.5in}{1in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{160,180,200}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\maintitle}{\begingroup

\pagecolor{backgroundcolor}

\centering

\vspace*{5\baselineskip}

{\Huge\scshape\textcolor{black}{\textbf{Matière \& Espace-Temps}}}

\vspace*{2\baselineskip}

{\large La théorie classique des champs relativistes}

\vfill

{\Large\scshape Mickey Mouse}

\vfill

    \newlength{\titlelength}
    \settowidth{\titlelength}{\Huge\scshape\textbf{Matière \& Espace-Temps}}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\titlelength]{example-image}}
    \end{figure}

\vfill

{\large\scshape Version number}

\par

\endgroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

% FRAME AROUND PAGE :
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
        \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
        \draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \maintitle
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

I don't know how to compose the title shown above, especially the big "&" with its transparency effect placed under the main title.  And I don't know how to load and use another font just for the main title, without changing the **lmodern** font used for the rest.  Any suggestion how to achieve this in LaTeX?

Comment: Which font would you like to use?

Comment: Well, I don’t know yet. I will have to try many of the fonts available in the LaTeX font catalogue.

Comment: Two questions: in the screenshot you posted first, Matière and  Espace-Temps do not use the same font size. Does it have to be reproduced? Next, the ampersand and the subtitle  are in this kind of blue-grey, which seems not really compatible with blue background (for legibility reasons). Could explain more details on what you expect?

Comment: Yes, the font size is different in the main title. The colors are arbitrary and could be adjusted later.

Comment: Why not just import what you did with pages?

Comment: @johannes, because the Pages document is uncomplete and needs a lot of work. I prefer to do everything in LaTeX.

Comment: You have the title part done in pages already. Simply import that part into your title page in LaTeX.

Answer (score 7):

## The whole thing using TikZ

After one commenter asked why I didn't do the whole titlepage in TikZ, I couldn't find rest until I've tried. Here is the result. I'm sure, the left aligned positioning in the center can be optimized. If anyone knows how, just drop me a line and I'll edit.

The code is a lot shorter and cleaner now:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,calc,backgrounds}

\tikzstyle{titlepage}=[text width=\paperwidth, text centered]

\definecolor{titlepage-background}{RGB}{160, 180, 200}
\definecolor{titlepage-title}{RGB}{26, 51, 74}
\definecolor{titlepage-ampersand}{RGB}{188, 205, 219}
\definecolor{titlepage-subtitle}{RGB}{97, 125, 150}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \fill[titlepage-background] (current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west);
            
            \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
            \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
            \draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
            
            \node [opacity=1,titlepage-ampersand,anchor=west] at (7.25,-3.5) {\scalebox{10}{\&}};
            \node [titlepage-title,anchor=west,xshift=.725in] at (0,-3) {\scalebox{4}{\textbf{Matière}}};
            \node [titlepage-title,anchor=west,xshift=.725in] at (0,-4.5) {\scalebox{3}{\textbf{Espace-Temps}}};
            \node [titlepage-subtitle,anchor=west,xshift=.725in] (theorie) at (0,-6) {\scalebox{1.1}{La théorie classique des champs relativistes}};
            \node [titlepage, titlepage-subtitle] at ([xshift=.25in]current page.center) {Mickey Mouse};
            
            \node[xshift=.25in, inner sep=0pt] (image) at ([yshift=7cm]current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=8.5cm]{example-image}};
            \node[align=left,black,anchor=north] at ([yshift=-1.5cm]image.south) {Version number};
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The output is quite nice, too:

[image: the whole thing using TikZ]

## The older messier solution

Well, the code certainly ain't pretty. But it is a start.

I personally think that what I've done defeats the purpose of using LaTeX since you have to manually fiddle with sizes, dimensions, and spacing as soon as you change the font family or the font size – the horror!

I justify my actions with the fact that you only have one title page, so this abomination I call code won't happen too often ;-)

#### I invite all the experts to chime in and edit away

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{1.5in}{1in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{160,180,200}
\definecolor{myamper}{RGB}{188, 205, 219}
\definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{97, 125, 150}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\newcommand*{\maintitle}{\begingroup

\pagecolor{backgroundcolor}

\centering

\vspace*{5\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}[t][5cm][b]{.5\textwidth}
{\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont\textbf{Matière}}

{\raisebox{-2.25em}[0pt][0pt]{\fontsize{95}{90}\selectfont\bfseries\noindent\hspace{1.35em}\textcolor{myamper} \&}}

{\fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\textbf{Espace-Temps}}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\textcolor{subtitle}{La théorie classique des champs relativistes}
\end{minipage}
\vfill

{\Large\ Mickey Mouse}

\vfill

    \newlength{\titlelength}
    \settowidth{\titlelength}{\Huge\textbf{Matière \& Espace-Temps}}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\titlelength]{example-image}}
    \end{figure}

\vfill

{\large Version number}

\par

\endgroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

% FRAME AROUND PAGE :
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
        \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
        \draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \maintitle
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image: title page]

Comment: since you use tikz would it not be easier to do the entire page with tikz rather than mixing tikz with minipage and maintitle  etc

Comment: @jsbibra, you are right, of course. I've tried, see above.